# How to debug Polymer project 1.x?

Tags: debugging, polymer, polymer-1.0

Information on the main site for [debugging *Polymer 0.5*](https://www.polymer-project.org/0.5/docs/polymer/runtime-config.html) is quite obsolete and doesn't work for *Polymer 1.0*.

I want to see some logs, so what I do:

```html
<script>
  window.Platform = {flags: {debug: true, log: 'bind,ready'}};    
</script>
<script src="/node_modules/webcomponents.js/webcomponents.js" debug></script>
<link rel="import" href="...">
```

Inside the import:

```html
<link rel="import" href="./bower_components/polymer/polymer.html">
<dom-module id="my-custom-element">...</dom-module>
```

Hit the url: `http://localhost:8080/index.html?debug&log=bind,ready,events`.
And finally I can't see any logs on the console.

*What is the right way of debugging Polymer 1.0*?

Answer (score 6):

If you are debugging *properties* (e.g. *data binding*), then read [properties guide](https://www.polymer-project.org/1.0/docs/devguide/properties.html), and make use of `observers` field. Here is an example:

```html
Polymer({
  is: 'portfolios-foobar',

  properties: {
    portfolios: {
      type: Array,
      value: [],
      notify: true,
      reflectToAttribute: true,
      observer: 'logChange'
    }
  },
  logChange: function(newValue, oldValue) {
    console.log('Changed! To:', newValue);
  },

  addFolio: function(folio) {
      this.push('portfolios', folio);
    },

  observers: [
     'logFor(portfolios)',
     'hackyObserver1(portfolios.*)',
     'hackyObserver2(portfolios.splices)'
  ],

  logFor: function(newValue, oldValue) {
    console.log('LogFor! To:', newValue);
  },
  hackyObserver1: function(changes) {
    console.log('One!', changes);
  },
  hackyObserver2: function(changeRecord) {
    console.log('Two! Splices!', changeRecord);
  }
});
```

Also after linking Polymer you can do:

```
Polymer.log = console.log.bind(console); // Not part of the public API, may be broken.
```

This will log element names being registered.

Answer (score 1):

I hope this is what your looking for `console.info();`

You can locate it at https://www.polymer-project.org/1.0/docs/devguide/events  "Event retargeting"

I would tack on a code sample but they already do that in the docs.